# Programmatic access to IE favorites

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar, favorites

I'm developing an IE addon (browser hosted object), and I need to query the browser favorites to find those that match a given query string. For example, I might want to find all favorites where the title or URL contain the word "software".

I've scoured all the relevant interfaces and the only option I've found is to read in and index all the files in the favorites folder myself. Is there an existing COM interface that I haven't found that would provide a more elegant solution?